# How to create BottomNavigationView with xamarin for Android API 19

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I tried to show a bottom navigation view on android phone with the API 19 with xamarin. It doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?

My code is

```
    Resources/layout/Main.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:gridSpec="1|8|#0093eeff|K:#ee8700ff:16,l:72,l:16,r|S:#83ee00ff:16,0,l:16,56,l:16,0,r">
  <!-- Header aligned to top -->
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:background="@drawable/header_bg">
    <!-- TODO Fill Dynamic, Format, Position-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prodCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="0 Artikel"
        style="@style/TotalTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


Resources/menu/navigation.xaml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
      android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
      android:title="title_home" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
      android:title="title_dashboard" />
</menu>
```

The problem is I get a white screen on the smartphone. How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

> My problem is I can't install the dependency "com.android.support:design:25.1.0", because it don't match with the API 19. The API is to old.

You can change your project target android version for Android 7.0 (API 24) or higher, then you can download this android support design.
[image]

Please note: keep the target version consistent with the compiled version
[image]

[image]

I do one sample about creating BottomNavigationView with xamarin for Android.

1.download and install Xamarin.Android.Support.Design in Manage NuGet package…

[image]
2.create a new `menu` folder in the `Resources` directory and add a new `.xml` file, creating `navigation_main.xml` in `Resources/menu/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
android:orderInCategory="0"
android:id="@+id/menu_genres"
android:enabled="true"
android:title="Genres"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"
app:showAsAction="always" />

  <item
android:orderInCategory="1"
android:id="@+id/menu_titles"
android:enabled="true"
android:title="Titles"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"
app:showAsAction="always" />

  <item
android:orderInCategory="2"
android:id="@+id/menu_stream"
android:enabled="true"
android:title="Stream"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"
app:showAsAction="always" />

  <item
android:orderInCategory="3"
android:id="@+id/menu_showtimes"
android:enabled="true"
android:title="Showtimes"
android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material"
app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

3.Bottom navigation works by replacing fragments when one of the items is selected. This means that our Android xml should also have a FrameLayout to swap in and out the fragments that will be displayed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="56dp"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     app:menu="@menu/navigation_main" />
```

For more info, please take a look the following article:
https://blog.xamarin.com/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/